# How to configure cgroup resource limits for desktop applications using official systemd features?

Tags: systemd, cgroup, resource-limiting

I've previously used `cgmanager` to group processes in separate `cgroups` and adjust memory and CPU limits as needed for each group. However, modern `systemd` doesn't want that other processes mess with `cgroups` so I guess I would need to configure `systemd` to do that instead. (To be exact, [Lennart Poettering (the author of systemd) thinks this way](https://lwn.net/Articles/575672/).)

I would want to e.g. define following:

- Specify group `desktop` and set *minimum* reserved RAM for that group to 1 GB, and automatically move my window manager (`marco`) and panel process (`mate-panel`) to it.
- Specify group `browsers` and set *maximum* RAM for that group to 20 GB, and automatically move all Firefox, Chrome and Opera processes to that group.
- The limits should be per user: when multiple desktop sessions are running (started via "Switch account" action without logging out previous account), each should have it's own cgroup with the limits above.

The important part is that I want those processes to get into the correct group whenever `/usr/bin/marco` or `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` is executed. That is, this automatic grouping should work even when wrappers such as `systemd-run` are *not* used. In short, no processes should be allowed to escape the cgroup containment.

With `cgmanager` this was really easy. You just created one config file and everything was set and it worked really well. However, I've been trying to look for documentation and I cannot figure out how to do the same thing with `systemd` alone.

Comment: One possible solution is to ignore what Poettering is saying and just install package `cgroup-tools` and use `cgrulesengd` combined with `/etc/cgrules.conf` to accomplish the above. As this goes against the plans of Poettering, the changes are there will be some unknown side-effects in long run but if nothing better is available, I think that's better than having no solution at all.

Comment: Did using `cgroup-tools` and `cgrulesengd` work?

Am I right that `cgroup-tools` under 22.04.2 LTS has Version 1 man pages?  The `cgcreate` man page is dated 2009-03-15 and talks about "all mounted controllers" as if there were multiple **cgroup** mounts, which is Version 1 language, not Version 2.

Using `cgcreate cpu:foobar` creates `/sys/fs/cgroup/foobar` (under the **cgroup2** mount point) and it puts controller **cpu** in the `cgroup.subtree_control` file, so **cpu** applies to sub-cgroups, not this cgroup.  Using `cgcreate '*:foobar'` idoes nothing.

Comment: I haven't used 22.04 (I'm still running 20.04) and I guess cgroup-tools and cgrulesengd might well NOT work anymore because 22.04 is supposed to have cgroup2 implementation.